# Make "Selected Context Only" persist in Chrome DevTools console settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools

I get a ton of misc errors from misc Chrome Extensions in my console. If I go to settings and check "Selected Context Only" then they go away and everything is good.

If I ever close that tab, or open a fresh Chrome window, "Selected Context Only" is unchecked again.

Is it possible to get this setting persisted forever and ever?

Comment: Having exactly the same problem over the few weeks, it's driving me insane!!

Comment: If I remember where this lead me, I think it's just a Chrome bug that is very very low priority for them, so don't hold your breath. :(

Comment: Yeah, i raised another bug with them so it gained some more attention, just watching for them to do something about it now.
In the mean time, i figured out that the endless console errors i am getting were actually from ghostly - so i just disabled it instead.

Comment: Bug to star: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=901863

Comment: Thank you @ZachB. This is becoming insanely irritating

Answer (score 3):

You can use the filter option as a workaround. For example I was able to hide warnings like 'DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for...' with regex `-/failed\sto\sload\ssource\smap/`

[image]

Also you can find a documentation for filtering here https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/reference#filter

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the same option form settings (f1) worked for me

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. I'm here just to give feedback on your answer to make it better. Would you be able to provide more details and links to the solution so that other devs would have a better grasp of the cause and solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with chrome and brave browser. To avoid showing the error messages comming from webpack dev server like the following screenshot. I defined negative filter in Console to filter them out.

```
/^((?!sockjs).)*$/
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Enable below option in the console settings. It will persist the "Selected Context Only"

[image]